# How do you check if a device is running Windows CE or Windows Mobile?

Tags: .net-3.5, windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-ce

Is there a programmatic way to figure out if a device is WinMobile or WinCE in .NET Compact Framework 3.5? Is there some property somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [`Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms.SystemSettings.Platform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsce.forms.systemsettings.platform(v=VS.90).aspx) Property.  It will tell you if you're running on Generic CE or WinMo.